# Merging two location blocks in nginx

Tags: nginx, location, url-rewriting

I want to merge 2 location blocks  in my nginx so that i can prevent unnecessary copy pasting and duplication 
Take the following block for example

```
location ~ \.php$ {
....
}
```

and

```
location ~ ^/somedirectory/(.+\.php)$ {
....
}
```

Here both location blocks contain exact data

How can i modify

```
location ~ \.php$ {
```

so that its works even for subdirectories

I think regex should be use here?
Can anyone guide me please

Regards

Comment: well i believe that it should already, the regex should match any php even if inside sub directory, just remove the sub directory location.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid nginx duplication in location blocks either use nginx includes OR use nested location blocks - A nested location block example follows ...

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://mywebfeservers;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Request-ID $uuid;
        proxy_set_header Via $via;

        location /aaa {
            # proxy_pass is not inherited, unsure about proxy_http_version
            proxy_pass http://mywebfeservers;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            # Prevent caching
            if_modified_since off;
        }
    }
```

Here all locations have these various headers set. Only the /aaa location prevents caching however BUT it still uses the same headers without repeating the config. Sadly, you DO HAVE TO repeat proxy pass since inheritance does not work with the proxy pass directive (for reasons of which I am unaware).